# How do I get a div to stretch full screen width outside of it's containing div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Having trouble getting the black bar at the bottom of the slider to stretch full-width on the screen.  It works on the left, but the right side is cut off at the container edge.  Using Master Slider if that's relative info. Any tips on how I can get that black bar to stretch all the way across?

http://designatwork.net/51fifteen/

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue

1. Remove `tranform` property from the div having class `ms-slide ms-sl-selected`
2. Remove `width` property from the div having class `ms-layer`. As div is absolutely positioned, set `left` and `right` values to 0 to make it full width
3. Remove `max-width` and `left` from div with class `ms-slide-layers` also

Although I feel, structure is not proper, having relative positions within absolute creates problems. Still above fix can save you from re-write.

Comment: All it did was move the graphics to the left, the black bar stayed the same...no luck.

Comment: Remove `max-width` and `left` from div with class `ms-slide-layers` also. Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

A few classes like `ms-slide-layers`, `ms-inner-controls-cont` and `ms-layer` have hardcoded values for `left`, `width` and, most limiting in this case, `max-width`.

I think this case would benefit from using the **viewport width** unit, `vw` by setting `width: 100vw;` you're telling it to be the width of the entire viewport.

Also, you don't need the `padding` and `margin` in 9999px. You can `position: absolute` the layer, have `bottom: 0` and then use reasonable `padding` and align the text according to your needs to get a better, cleaner result.

Comment: Also, just a quick side note: the page crashed every four out of five times I loaded it and clicked on the slider. Something there is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

First set a position (anything other than static) to its parent element. Then set the black bar's position to absolute. This way, it will be relative to its nearest parent element that contains a position. Next, stretch it out by either using height and width properties, or use directional positions (top, bottom, left, right). If youll use directional positions then use both left and right simultaneously and the black bar will expand across the screen.